# Where can I ask this Android question?

Tags: support, questions

I've asked this question on [Android SE](http://android.stackexchange.com):
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20411/how-many-developer-accounts-i-can-register-with-google-play-aka-android-market

The question was closed as Off Topic. Given reason: Question is related to the Android Market from a developer's point of view.

Now, I want to know where it can be asked. Clearly, Stack Overflow can't accept it because its not a programming question.

Comment: Related: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/1465)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe there is no appropriate site as of now for this type of question. You should ask Google for the appropriate information.

Note that there is an [App Stores](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) proposal in commitment phase on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) that you might want to look into.

Comment: That "App Stores" proposal has been removed.